# Split String with Spring EL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el, string-operations

I needs to split string with value **$$** in spring context xml file, I have tried below things, but no luck :( Anyone can help please?

In java it's working something like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.err.println("localhost$$8080".split("\\$\\$")[1]);
    }
```

**My tries**

- `<constructor-arg name="port" value="#{'#{config.getNode()}'.split('\\$\\$')[1]}" />`
- `<constructor-arg name="port" value="#{'#{config.getNode()}'.split('$$')[1]}" />`
- `<constructor-arg name="port" value="#{'#{config.getNode()}'.split('\$\$')[1]}" />`
- `<constructor-arg name="port" value="#{'#{config.getNode()}'.split('\\u0024\\u0024')[1]}" />`

**NOTE** : Please assume that `config.getNode()` will give value "localhost$$8080".

Comment: Hi @NehaShettar, it's not working :(

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@Value("#{config.getNode().split('\\$\\$')[1]}")
private String port;
```

or in the XML:

```
<constructor-arg name="port" value="#{config.getNode().split('\\$\\$')[1]}" />
```

Comment: Interesting, just did a quick test from my end locally. What's the error raised?

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`, basically it's not considering splitter string, so everything goes into `[0]` part.

Comment: May be different spring version?? with which version have you tested?

Comment: Mine's 3.2.0-RELEASE.  Oooh, out of interest, what happens when you print out `[0]` in the split, instead of `[1]`?

Comment: Its giving me whole string

Comment: Interesting. Maybe try changing your `config.getNode()` to return `localhost:8080` first then change the split to use `:` and see if it works to debug the split. The only reason the split() would return the whole string is if it can't find the split string you used...

Comment: that's the main problem @Gabe, we needs to find a solution for $$, however it's coming from other server, so I can't change it

Comment: Can you test your code with spring core version `5.0.0.M4` ?

Comment: if I use `##` as separator, the I can get proper value with `#{config.getNode().split('##')[1]}`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below:

```
 <constructor-arg name="port" 
      value="#{config.getNode().split('\\u0024\\u0024')[1]}" />
```

Comment: Hi @javaguy, it will not work as I needs to access method, not property

Comment: You can try the updated answer, this works, tested with a method

Comment: what is the error you are getting? For me it works fine

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBound`, basically it's not considering splitter string, so everything goes into `[0]` part.

Comment: Are you sure that your method returns `localhost$$8080`, just debug and double check that again which would be the issue, the string should be exactly like `localhost$$8080` without any quotes

Comment: Yes, already double checked that thing before posting the question! It's returning me `127.0.0.1$$6379`

Comment: I am using spring core version `5.0.0.M4` can you test with that?

Comment: if I use `##` as separator, the I can get proper value with `#{config.getNode().split('##')[1]}`